# Can a SQLite user-defined function take a row argument?

Tags: sqlite, rust, rusqlite

They [are described as](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) scalar, but I think that refers to the return type rather than the arguments.

I'm trying to define one in rust that will provide a `TEXT` value derived from other columns in the row, for convenience/readability at point of use, I'd like to call it as `select myfunc(mytable) from mytable` rather than explicitly the columns that it derives.

The [`rusqlite` example](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.24.2/rusqlite/struct.Connection.html#example) simply gets an argument as `f64`, so it's not that clear to me how it might be possible to interpret it as a row and retrieve columnar values from within it. Nor have I been able to find examples in other languages.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem possible.

`func(tablename)` syntax that I'm familiar with seems to be PostgreSQL-specific; SQLite supports `func(*)` but when `func` is user-defined it receives zero arguments, not one (structured) or `N` (all columns separately) as I expected.